# Hide menu link depending on variable being true or false

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following Typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    var isLoggedIn = false;

  }

}
```

Which has the following Html template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">
   Site Name
  </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/sign-up']">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="isLoggedIn"><a [routerLink]="['/logout']">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see if in the last menu link (logout) I'm using `*ngIf` to either display the link whether the user is logged in or not.  At present I'm hardcoding the value to false, if I change this to true, the link still remains hidden for some reason.

Please be aware I'm learning Angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {



  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working, can you tell me what the difference is from having it outside ngOnInit and when it's inside?

Comment: variable **created/initialised**(for example using var) inside functions are scoped to that function. That means it cannot be accessed from outside the function. The template has access to scope of the component and can only see variables that are initialised within that component. By moving it, we changed the scope from of the variable from the function to the component.

Also note that 'var''s scope is limited to a function while 'let' and 'const' are limited to any block (`{ let initializedInBlock = 0 }`)